# How to create and configure a linked server to connect to MySQL in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssms

I need create and configure a linked server to connect to MySQL in SQL Server Management Studio

This is the [tutorial](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-to-connect-to-mysql-in-sql-server-management-studio/)

I follow the instructions step by step but in the end the result is the following

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

please, can you help me?

Comment: Share the SQL that is being run to generate this error. An image of the error doesn't tell us anything, and if you're following the instructions and implementing them correctly, you likely wouldn't be getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 32Bit ODBC SYSTEM dsn connection, make sure the Test connection works.

Then run the following in your SQL Server Management Studio

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'<somelinkname>', @srvproduct=N'MYSQL', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'<32 Bit DNS Name >'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'<somelinkname>',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'<mysql user>',@rmtpassword='<mysql pwd>'
GO
```